# Undefined reference to `WinMain@16' error when compile with gcc

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer

I'm going to run a simple program constructed with Flex an Bison.

Here are my codes.

***Flex file (calc.l)***

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "tt.tab.h"
%}

/* %option noyywrap */
%%

[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?([eE][0-9]+)?  {yylval.f = atof(yytext); return NUM;}
[-+()*/]                        {return yytext[0];}
[\t\f\v\n]                      {;}

%%

int yywrap() {return -1}
```

***Bison  file (tt.y)***

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int yylex();
void yyerror(char *msg);
%}

%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int yylex();
%}

%union {
    float f;
}

%token <f> NUM
%type <f> E T F

%%
S : E           {printf("f\n", $1);} 
  ;

E : E '+' T     {$$ = $1 + $3}
  | T           {$$ = $1;}
  ;

T : T '*' F     {$$ = $1 * $3}
  | F           {$$ = $1;}
  ;

F : '(' E ')'       {$$ = $2;}
  | '-' F           {$$ = -$2;}
  | NUM         {$$ = $1;}
%%

void yyerror(char *msg) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
    exit(1); 
}
```

To compile I follow follow commands in cmd.

***Bison -d tt.y***

***Flex calc.l***

***gcc lex.yy.c tt.tab.c -o calc***

when I run last gcc comman it got error like this.

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xb0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is the problem in my codes or any. Thanks for any consideration :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not define the *main* function, the code generated by flex and bison do not define the *main* function, you have to define it by yourself else the program do not have an entry point.

You have problems in your definitions :

- in tt.y `{printf("f\n", $1);}` have a format not compatible with an argument, must be ``{printf("%f\n", $1);}` ?
- in tt.y declare *yyerror* in the header with the declaration of *yylex*
- in calc.l `int yywrap() {return -1}` must be `int yywrap() {return -1;}`

The minimal *main* definition is :

```
int main()
{
   yyparse();
   return 0;
}
```

you can put it with the definition of *yyerror* in tt.y

Comment: Where I have to define main() funtion, in .y file or .l file ?

Comment: @Dhananjaya I edited my answer, please reread it. I think a `%start` is also missing in the bison file

Comment: Thanks.. we have t define main() { return yyparse();} in .y file. I got it. :)

Comment: `yywrap` needs to return 1, not -1. Although it would be better to uncomment `%option noyywrap`, and not define `yywrap` at all.